# what is "T!" represent in socket connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection, serial-port

i have open [java socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) for read serial data on localhost, but the when i try more times to read data then i get just two bytes which are `T!`. i don't know what this two characters represent ?? and what the cause to receive these characters ?

I think they are used as Termination or something for connection !!!

i try to search for it on [google](https://www.google.jo/) but it give me T connection or terminal.

Answer (score 1):

They have no specific meaning. It's probably just what was left over in your buffer from the previous read.